# How to remove facial hairs in girls without threading/bleaching using natural products?

Tags: personal-care, hair

Due to hormonal imbalances tiny hairs appears on the face of girls usually in their puberty. It can be removed through threading ,which remains for a few days only and it is a painful process for girls of that age usually in teens. So is there any better way to remove it effectively without threading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hair is really thick then I would say consult a doctor, as this may signal a more important problem. If the hair is just a few then I would say leave them, as removing them may encourage more to grow.  However, I can think of only 2 really good solutions:

- Pluck the hair out. Some people may think this is to time consuming, but if you have a couple of hairs this will be fast. There is some pain, but doing it fast will lessen pain. Placing a warm towel over your face before, also makes it feels better.
- Wax your face. This is painful, waxing any part of your body is painful. But it shouldn't be to bad or to long. There are even ways to do it at home naturally. [Link](http://www.livestrong.com/article/103205-wax-upper-lip-home-homemade/#page=1).

---

Alternate ways are:

[From this link](http://www.stylecraze.com/articles/simple-ways-to-remove-upper-lip-hair-naturally/):

- Mix turmeric and water equally and apply it to the lip. Apply it for about 30 minutes and let it harden. Do this for awhile, 4 weeks, and the hair should not have grown anymore.
- Using depilatory pastes may burn and shaving will make it come back like a forest.

Comment: I think the "plucking causes more hair to grow back" is a wives tale. http://www.today.com/health/myth-busted-does-plucking-gray-hairs-make-more-grow-back-8C11565154

Comment: But plucking causes the hair to grow back bristly. Laser removal - 3 or 4 sessions for a small amount of hair, job done, for life. Works best on dark hair.

Comment: The FDA has made it illegal to call Laser hair removal "permanent" because the hair eventually grows back in most cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_hair_removal . Electrolysis is the only way to permanently remove hair. But, this is not a simple, cheap and "natural" way to remove hair, like Happy is looking for. :)